# Is there a way to make this bruteforce password cracker faster?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

So I'm pretty new to c++, and this is the second program I've ever written in it.  The first program was a complete mess but it worked, this program I decided to just put all in one file.  My problem is, it just runs incredibly slowly.  I'm pretty sure it's because of just how many characters it has to iterate through, but the requirements are that it can crack a password of a specific length with any special characters like these.  Other than the number of characters it has to go through I'm not sure what, if anything, is making it run so slowly.  I'm wondering if it's something I've done that is improper and making it take so long.  Is this just about how fast a password cracker like this can run?

```
// Password Cracker.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

std::string convertToString(char*, int);
void passwordBruteForcer(std::string, long long, long long);

std::atomic<bool> isPasswordFound = false;
std::string foundString;

int main()
{
    // Given some count of the amount of symbols that can exist in the password
    // We will calulcate how many possible passwords there are then divide work evenly between threads
    // In this case the possible symbols are all ascii codes from 32 to 126
    int numOfSymbols = 95;

    // Declarations;
    int numberOfThreads = 8;
    std::string password;
    std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads;

    // Loop waits for correct user input (problem required that password length be 5, change this if you want)
    while (true)
    {
        // Prompting user input
        std::cout << "Please enter a password of length 5 \n";
        std::cout << "password: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, password);
        if (password.length() == 5)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid password \n";
        }
    }

    long long amountOfPossiblePasswords = pow(numOfSymbols, password.length());

    // Creates threads running brute force cracker
    for (int threadNumber = 1; threadNumber <= numberOfThreads; threadNumber++)
    {
        long long startingNumber = (amountOfPossiblePasswords * (threadNumber - 1)) / numberOfThreads;
        long long endNumber = (amountOfPossiblePasswords * threadNumber) / numberOfThreads;
        long long remainder = amountOfPossiblePasswords % numberOfThreads;

        if (threadNumber == numberOfThreads)
        {
            vecOfThreads.push_back(std::thread(passwordBruteForcer, password, startingNumber, endNumber + remainder));
        }
        else
        {
            vecOfThreads.push_back(std::thread(passwordBruteForcer, password, startingNumber, endNumber));
        }
    }

    // Wait to join thread
    for (std::thread & th : vecOfThreads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }

    // Prints the password the algorithm found
    if (isPasswordFound)
    {
        std::cout << foundString;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Will go through all "printable" ASCII characters
void passwordBruteForcer(std::string passStr, long long startingNumber, long long endNumber)
{
    int firstChar = 32;
    int lastChar = 126;
    int length = passStr.length();
    int numOfChar = 95;
    int numOfTries = pow(numOfChar, length);

    char* guess = new char[length];

    // Converts decimal to base num of chars then puts that char into array
    // For ex. 0 will be first char, and a 1 will be the next char, the number that represents the amount of possible passwords
    // will set this to be all lastChar

    long long numToBeConvert = startingNumber;

    for (int i = (length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        guess[i] = firstChar + (numToBeConvert % numOfChar);
        numToBeConvert /= numOfChar;
    }

    // This creates a string based on initialized guess then tests it
    std::string comparisonPasswordString = convertToString(guess, length);

    if (comparisonPasswordString == passStr)
    {
        isPasswordFound = true;
        foundString = comparisonPasswordString;

        delete[] guess;
        return;
    }

    // This loop goes from startingNumber to endNumber testing all passwords
    for(long long i = startingNumber; i < endNumber; i++)
    {
        if (isPasswordFound == true)
        {
            break;
        }

        long long numForGuess = i;
        for (int j = (length - 1); j >= 0; j--)
        {
            guess[j] = firstChar + (numForGuess % numOfChar);
            numForGuess /= numOfChar;
        }
        comparisonPasswordString = convertToString(guess, length);

        if (comparisonPasswordString == passStr)
        {
            isPasswordFound = true;
            foundString = comparisonPasswordString;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    delete[] guess;
}


std::string convertToString(char* charArr, int length)
{
    std::string convString;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        convString.push_back(charArr[i]);
    }
    return convString;
}
```

Comment: convertToString doesn't need a function at all.  std::string has a constructor that takes a char* and a length: constructor #4 at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string  And even if you did need a function you wouldn't push_back one character at a time without reserving space first.

Comment: First of all, you've enabled compiler optimizations, yes?  Second, look into profiling tools and learn how to use them.  Third, think about every place you copy data in your inner loop, and think about whether it's necessary.

Comment: Consider using OpenMP for such a computation. It will make your code shorter, simpler and cleaner so then you can perform complex optimizations more easily. That being said, `convertToString` is not efficient is probably slowing down your application. Try to remove allocations in hot loops as much as possible (possibly using custom allocators).